# Kerning and alternates with "ti"

Tags: typesetting, glyphs, kerning

So I'm familiar with some kerning/alternates used with certain letter combinations, like "fi" being combined so the top of the f hangs down into the dot of the i. What about "ti" in a serif font?

Using Prata, is it ok to have the ti as is or should something be done about it? Kerning or alternates like the fi example?

[image]

Comment: Related: [What are some common kerning pairs?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68245/23061)

Comment: Whether or not to use a ligature for a glyph pair, assuming the typeface contains one, is really your choice. More "style" than "rule"

Comment: I see no problem with the "ti". And I don't think it is a letter pair that is known to require special attention (like "VA" for example). In your case it looks just fine. And it will with most (good) fonts since they should contain kerning values for the most common glyph pairs.