# The logic of kerning subtables

Tags: font-design, kerning

Referring to this thread: [The logic of kerning classes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117434/the-logic-of-kerning-classes), I considered various lookups of some fonts (Adobe Premiere, Minion, EBGaramond...) to understand better the way of build them and the relative subtables. Now, a lot of font has at least two subtables:

`'kern' horizontal Kerning Lookup 0 per glyph data...`

`'kern' horizontal Kerning Lookup 0 per kerning class...`

But in certain cases the first one contains only a few symbols, in other cases a lot of fonts glyphs. So, 
what is the exact role of the the subtable *per glyph data*? Is it better to have only a table *per kerning class* (for lettes glyphs), or is it reasonable to create a subtable for Uppercase-Uppercase, another one for Uppercase-lowercase and so on? Or is it the same?

Comment: No advice or directions?