# How does a font designer decide about kerning?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-design, glyphs

Designing a font is a cumbersome task as each glyph should be drawn. However, finding the right kerning is something that puzzles me.

A font can have thousands of kerning, and there are even more possibilities.

***I am curious how a designer finds the right kerning?***

Does a designer check thousands of pairs to find the best kerning for each pair? Or is there a trick (general rule) to find the kerning systematically?

Comment: I dont think the task of drawing glyphs is necceserily super cumbersome. Kerning is a bit annoying though. There are many ways. One can do this, usually you do it so that the bearing solves most cases then you do it by group for example a letters with straight right side "IlJd..." Kern the same way against left sidw round letters eodgcq maybe a so you do one kerning for them. Or you use auto kerning etc.

Comment: @joojaa I read about auto kerning, but it made me wonder: if auto kerning can work, why not doing auto kerning at the program level instead of adjusting the font file?

Comment: adobes software gives you that option.

Comment: @Googlebot, because the result isn't nearly as good as what a human can achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some common kerning pairs?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68245/19174). (Yes, the titular question is somewhat different, but the answers should address your question.) I don’t want to hammer this closed, however, so if you agree, please *flag → a duplicate.*

Comment: @Wolff im not sure this is true anymore. It certainly was true when the font engines were created. The problem being not that computer could not do that for you but rather that there is no way for you to describe effectively what choice you want it to execute.

Comment: @joojaa, yeah computers could do many things, but if telling it what you want it to do takes longer than just doing it yourself, it's not really useful.

Comment: @joojaa PDF is probably the most common language communicating with both printer and screen the place of glyphs. There is no such option instructing the PDF viewers. We have to set the kerning by the `TJ` operator.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft my question is about common practice. I understand that common pairs might be the starting point, but they are few. There are often thousands of kerning in a font. Of course, most of them are probably automatic because `1` or `2` does not meaningfully change the location of a glyph.

Comment: @Googlebot PDF is supposed to reproduce faithfully what the authoring application did. Nothing less nothing more. It needs no such features. So only an authoring application needs such features. in reality there is only so many kernings you need, its always a tradeof. You do what you can and adjust as you go forward. 1000 may seem a lot upfront. But one change every now and then adds up. Or then the alternative is you make no font.

Comment: Also one group of kerning creates easily 100 individual kernings

Comment: @Googlebot: *my question is about common practice.* – Well, you may ask this, but I don’t think anybody has surveyed font designers for what they do. (Also, who qualifies as a font designer in the first place?) You will probably find everything between what is described in the linked questions over people to completely relying on automatisation to nothing at all.

Comment: *I understand that common pairs might be the starting point, but they are few. There are often thousands of kerning in a font.* – The primary point of [my answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68282/19174) to the linked question is how to efficiently kern a font with thousands of kerning pairs and without using auto-kerning at all (not that I want to condemn auto-kerning; it just didn’t work for my particular font).